# Count doublet or triplet with gcd as 1

Tags: algorithm

Given a sequence of n numbers and we have to find out all the sets of k numbers such that their g.c.d is 1.

More specifically, for a given value of k, we need to find the number of groups, each having k numbers, such that the gcd of all elements in that group is 1.

Two groups are said to be different if they have atleast one element which is at different indexes in the sequence.

**Note**: Gcd of a single number is taken as the number itself.

**Example** : Let N=4 and K=3 and sequence be : [1,2,4,4] then here answer is 3.

**Explanation** : Three distinct groups can be formed

```
1,2,4 
1,2,4 
1,4,4
```

Note that the first two groups are distinct as the position of 4 is different in the two groups.

Main point is K=1 or K=2 or K=3 . I can't go for all the subsequences. So please help to solve this problem

Comment: What part are you struggling with?

Comment: K = 1 is trivial. How large can N be? How large are the numbers in the sequence? What's your current approach?

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeh K=1 is trivial N can be at max 10^5

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I want to know is their better way other than going for all subsequences ?

Comment: You didn't answer all the questions in my comment.

Comment: @NiklasB. Numbers can be at max 10^5. Also my current approach is recursive one. Their are 2^n subsequences .So thats inefficient

Comment: This might help: https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/46074/coprime3-editorial